# How to add data from items with the same PK together

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql query

```sql
SELECT product.productNum, product.description, prod_location.quantityOnHand 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN prod_location ON prod_location.productNum = product.productNum
```

and this is the output.

```
productNum | description | quantityOnHand
660        | Reflex Paper| 100
660        | Reflex Paper| 95
660        | Reflex Paper| 64
661        | Window Clean| 200
661        | Window Clean| 67
661        | Window Clean| 38
662        | Acid        | 300
662        | Acid        | 100
662        | Acid        | 100
663        | Pens        | 400
663        | Pens        | 200
663        | Pens        | 153
664        | Door Mats   | 200
```

How do I get it so the quantityOnHand from each productNum is added together, so instead of their being 3 lines for Reflex Paper, it just says

```
productNum | description | quantityOnHand
660        | Reflex Paper| 259
661        | Window Clean| 305
662        | Acid        | 500
663        | Pens        | 753
664        | Door Mats   | 200
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT product.productNum, product.description, SUM(prod_location.quantityOnHand) as quantityOnHand
FROM product 
INNER JOIN prod_location ON prod_location.productNum = product.productNum
GROUP BY product.productNum
```

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between the `product` table and the `prod_locatoin` table is one-to-many. and `prduct.productNum` is unique

```
SELECT product.productNum, product.description, SUM(prod_location.quantityOnHand) as quantityOnHand
FROM product 
INNER JOIN prod_location ON prod_location.productNum = product.productNum
GROUP BY product.productNum
```